# XSLT paged display some calculated node values along with previous line values retrieved over next line (II)

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Checked back again with another request which is linked on previous one, depicted over the following stackoverflow link:

[XSLT get some calculated node value over next line node's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302887/xslt-get-some-calculated-node-value-over-next-line-nodes-value)

I won't repeat the whole problem's details as they could be checked out 
through mentioned link.
 This second new request is also based over that upkeep share bills list .xml file provided and there is a need for displaying the same data but paged (pagination). 
 Suppose I have dozens of lines in that .xml file, naturally one should do some pagination about it for a good, clean and effective display.
 In order to do that, I just used first michael.hor257k's solution for displaying the data and another guy's solution for pagination.
 These two approaches I did assembled over that .xsl file provided; but .. It didn't work !
 Individually they're working smoothly, but put together the whole process fails ...
  Following I'll give you both my .xml file and that associated .xsl and some small .js file (which is helping for proper pagination) and I'm asking you guys to support me as I'm unable to come up with a solution.
 I know it's a bit complicated ... but .. that's the stuff I needed to display 
 Thank you again very much ... and sorry for unable sort things out myself ..

**1. xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <upkeepList> 
  <upkShare month_year="11_16-12_16" post_dte="01-20-17" due="02-04-17">
  <OpngBlnce>22</OpngBlnce>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>77</mnthCrrntAmnt> 
   <Rcpt dte="01-26-17" No="5725">
    <amnt>22</amnt>
    <descrpt>"11/16" upkeep </descrpt>
   </Rcpt>
   <Rcpt dte="01-26-17" No="5726">
    <amnt>41</amnt>
    <descrpt>"12/16" upkeep </descrpt>
   </Rcpt>
  </upkShare>

  <upkShare month_year="01_17-02_17" post_dte="03-17-17" due="04-03-17">
   <OpngBlnce/> 
   <mnthCrrntAmnt>74</mnthCrrntAmnt>
   <Rcpt dte="03-30-17" No="5783">
    <amnt>50</amnt>
    <descrpt>"01/17-02/17" upkeep</descrpt>
    </Rcpt>
  </upkShare>

  <upkShare month_year="03-17" post_dte="04-16-17" due="05-02-17"> 
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>55</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="05-10-17" No="5815">
   <amnt>40</amnt>
   <descrpt>"03/17-04/17" upkeep 1</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
  <Rcpt dte="05-15-17" No="5825">
   <amnt>9</amnt>
   <descrpt>"03/17-04/17" upkeep 2</descrpt>
  </Rcpt> 
 </upkShare>

 <upkShare month_year="04_17-05_17" post_dte="06-05-17" due="06-30-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>64</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="06-14-17" No="5858">
   <amnt>37</amnt>
    <descrpt>"05/17" upkeep 1</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
  <Rcpt dte="06-18-17" No="5863">
   <amnt>21</amnt>
   <descrpt>"05/17" upkeep 2</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
 </upkShare>

 <upkShare month_year="06_17" post_dte="07-16-17" due="07-30-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>45</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="07-28-17" No="5948">
   <amnt>38</amnt>
   <descrpt>"06/17" upkeep</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
 </upkShare> 

  <upkShare month_year="07_17" post_dte="08-16-17" due="08-31-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>54</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="07-28-17" No="6002">
   <amnt>33</amnt>
   <descrpt>"07/17" upkeep 1</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
  <Rcpt dte="08-02-17" No="6017">
   <amnt>12</amnt>
   <descrpt>"07/17" upkeep 2</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
 </upkShare>

 <upkShare month_year="08_17" post_dte="09-19-17" due="09-31-17">
  <OpngBlnce></OpngBlnce>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>41</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="09-29-17" No="6026">
   <amnt>41</amnt>
   <descrpt>"08/17" upkeep </descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
 </upkShare>

 <upkShare month_year="09_17" post_dte="10-16-17" due="10-31-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>34</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="10-26-17" No="6050" >
   <amnt>34</amnt>
   <descrpt>"09/17" upkeep </descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
 </upkShare>

 <upkShare month_year="10_17" post_dte="11-18-17" due="11-31-17">
  <OpngBlnce></OpngBlnce>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>47</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="11-27-17" No="6052">
   <amnt>10</amnt>
   <descrpt>upkeep amount 1</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
  <Rcpt dte="11-28-17" No="6084">
   <amnt>8</amnt>
   <descrpt>upkeep amount 2</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
  <Rcpt dte="11-30-17" No="6104">
   <amnt>27</amnt>
   <descrpt>upkeep amount 3</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
 </upkShare>

 <upkShare month_year="11_17" post_dte="12-15-17" due="01-07-18">
  <OpngBlnce></OpngBlnce>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>8</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="01-06-18" No="6135">
   <amnt>17</amnt>
   <descrpt>some upkeep amount</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
  </upkShare>
 </upkeepList>
```

**2.xsl file :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> <xsl:decimal-format name="coerce" NaN="0" />
  <xsl:variable name="upkshr">  <!-- upkshr varbl -->
    <xsl:for-each select="upkShare">  
  <upkp pstdte="{@post_dte}" rltedmnthyr = "{@month_year}"  ob = "{format-number(OpngBlnce, '#', 'coerce')}"
  mcamnt = "{format-number(mnthCrrntAmnt, '#','coerce')}" term = "{@due}" rcptsum = "{format-number(sum(Rcpt/amnt), '#','coerce')}" /> <!-- missing ob node's value forced to zero -->
  </xsl:for-each> 
 </xsl:variable> 
 <xsl:param name="size" select="4"/>
 <xsl:template match="upkeepList">

<html> 
 <head>  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scrpt_pagn.js"></script> 
   <h3 style="margin-left:45">Upkeep share bills list</h3>
 </head> 
 <body onload="onInitialize()">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$upkshr[position() mod $size = 1]">
   <xsl:with-param name="pages" select="ceiling(count($upkshr) div $size)"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="$upkshr"> <xsl:param name="pages"/>
   <xsl:variable name="page" select="position()"/>

  <table border="1" id='content{$page}' width="300" height="170" style="text-align:center;margin-left:50; margin-top:22px; display:none">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
     <th>UpkpShare_Prd</th> <th>PostDate</th> <th>InitBalance</th> 
     <th>UpkpShare_Amount</th>
     <th>DueDate</th> <th>FullAmnt</th> <th>FullAmntPayed</th> 
     <th>AmntDue</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="self::$upkshr | following-sibling::$upkshr[position()&lt;$size]"> 
     <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($upkshr)/upkp"> 
      <tr>
       <td> <xsl:value-of select="@rltedmnthyr"/> </td> <!-- relatd mnthly year -->
       <td> <xsl:value-of select="@pstdte"/> </td> <!-- post date -->
   <xsl:variable name="initblnc" select="sum(preceding-sibling::upkp/@ob) + sum(preceding-sibling::upkp/@mcamnt) - sum(preceding-sibling::upkp/@rcptsum) + @ob" /> 
       <td> <xsl:value-of select="$initblnc"/> <!-- initblnc = initial balance / opening balance -->
       </td>
       <td> <xsl:value-of select="@mcamnt"/> </td> <!-- monthly upkeep share amount -->
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@term"/> </div> </td>  <!-- due -->
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="$initblnc + @mcamnt"/> </td>  <!-- full amount  -->
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@rcptsum"/> </td>   <!-- full amount payed -->
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="$initblnc + @mcamnt - @rcptsum"/> </td>  <!-- amount due / closing balance -->
     </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="8"> 
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$page = 1">
     <xsl:text>pag</xsl:text> <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="$page"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/>      
     <xsl:value-of select="$pages"/>      
     <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
     <a href="#{$page+1}" onclick="nextPage({$page+1})">&gt;</a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$page = $pages">
    <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
     <a href="#{$page - 1}" onclick="prevPage({$page - 1})">&lt;</a>      
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:text>pag</xsl:text>  
    <xsl:value-of select="' '"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$page"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/>  
    <xsl:value-of select="$pages"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <a href="#{$page - 1}" onclick="prevPage({$page - 1})">&lt;</a>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:text>pag</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>      
    <xsl:value-of select="$page"/>      
    <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$pages"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
     <a href="#{$page+1}" onclick="nextPage({$page+1})">&gt;</a>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
   </td> </tr> 
   </table>   
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

.. and finally .js file:

```
function onInitialize()
{
 var i = 1;
  document.getElementById("content"+i).style.display="" ; 
}

function nextPage(num)
{
 document.getElementById("content"+num).style.display="";
 num--;
 document.getElementById("content"+num).style.display="none"; 
}

function prevPage(num)
{
 document.getElementById("content"+num).style.display="";
 num++;
 document.getElementById("content"+num).style.display="none";
}
```

This would be it.
 Again, you guys, help me with this (relatively difficult) issue !!
 Thank you very, very much in advance !!

Comment: "but put together the whole process fails"? What does that mean exactly, at least tell us the exact error message(s), describe which result in terms of the HTML output you want and which one you get instead.

Comment: Doesn't `xsl:template match="$upkshr"` for instance just give you an XSLT compile time error? Or are you running that XSLT 1 stylesheet with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor?

Comment: you know, the whole iteration process is now taking place inside that $upkshr variable where one builded that fragment tree.
 I used altova xml spy for debuging (and as altova doesen't support exsl="http://exslt.org/common" function extension, there  - down in altova - i seted up xslt 2.0). 
 But in my opera browser i'm forced to use xslt 1.0 as current browsers does't support xslt other than 1.0 !

 So, in altova xml spy, the follwing errors encountered :
  1 .xsl:template match="$cteintr 
  2. xsl:for-each select="self::$cteintr | following-sibling::$cteintr[position()&lt;$size]"

Comment: ... but seems that the whole logic , as I presented is wrong somehow ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I have managed to understood the HTML you want to create but the following produces some three "pages"/tables for your input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> <xsl:decimal-format name="coerce" NaN="0" />
  <xsl:variable name="upkshr">  <!-- upkshr varbl -->
    <xsl:for-each select="*/upkShare">  
  <upkp pstdte="{@post_dte}" rltedmnthyr = "{@month_year}"  ob = "{format-number(OpngBlnce, '#', 'coerce')}"
  mcamnt = "{format-number(mnthCrrntAmnt, '#','coerce')}" term = "{@due}" rcptsum = "{format-number(sum(Rcpt/amnt), '#','coerce')}" /> <!-- missing ob node's value forced to zero -->
  </xsl:for-each> 
 </xsl:variable> 

 <xsl:variable name="upkp-set" select="exsl:node-set($upkshr)/upkp"/>

 <xsl:param name="size" select="4"/>

 <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>
 <xsl:template match="upkeepList">

<html> 
 <head>  
   <script type="text/javascript">
function onInitialize()
{
 var i = 1;
  document.getElementById("content"+i).style.display="" ; 
}

function nextPage(num)
{
 document.getElementById("content"+num).style.display="";
 num--;
 document.getElementById("content"+num).style.display="none"; 
}

function prevPage(num)
{
 document.getElementById("content"+num).style.display="";
 num++;
 document.getElementById("content"+num).style.display="none";
}
   </script> 
   <h3 style="margin-left:45">Upkeep share bills list</h3>
 </head> 
 <body onload="onInitialize()">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$upkp-set[position() mod $size = 1]">
   <xsl:with-param name="pages" select="ceiling(count($upkp-set) div $size)"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="upkp"> <xsl:param name="pages"/>
   <xsl:variable name="page" select="position()"/>

  <table border="1" id='content{$page}' width="300" height="170" style="text-align:center;margin-left:50; margin-top:22px; display:none">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
     <th>UpkpShare_Prd</th> <th>PostDate</th> <th>InitBalance</th> 
     <th>UpkpShare_Amount</th>
     <th>DueDate</th> <th>FullAmnt</th> <th>FullAmntPayed</th> 
     <th>AmntDue</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::upkp[position()&lt;$size]"> 
      <tr>
       <td> <xsl:value-of select="@rltedmnthyr"/> </td> <!-- relatd mnthly year -->
       <td> <xsl:value-of select="@pstdte"/> </td> <!-- post date -->
   <xsl:variable name="initblnc" select="sum(preceding-sibling::upkp/@ob) + sum(preceding-sibling::upkp/@mcamnt) - sum(preceding-sibling::upkp/@rcptsum) + @ob" /> 
       <td> <xsl:value-of select="$initblnc"/> <!-- initblnc = initial balance / opening balance -->
       </td>
       <td> <xsl:value-of select="@mcamnt"/> </td> <!-- monthly upkeep share amount -->
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@term"/>  </td>  <!-- due -->
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="$initblnc + @mcamnt"/> </td>  <!-- full amount  -->
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@rcptsum"/> </td>   <!-- full amount payed -->
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="$initblnc + @mcamnt - @rcptsum"/> </td>  <!-- amount due / closing balance -->
     </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="8"> 
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$page = 1">
     <xsl:text>pag</xsl:text> <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="$page"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/>      
     <xsl:value-of select="$pages"/>      
     <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
     <a href="#{$page+1}" onclick="nextPage({$page+1})">&gt;</a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$page = $pages">
    <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
     <a href="#{$page - 1}" onclick="prevPage({$page - 1})">&lt;</a>      
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:text>pag</xsl:text>  
    <xsl:value-of select="' '"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$page"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/>  
    <xsl:value-of select="$pages"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <a href="#{$page - 1}" onclick="prevPage({$page - 1})">&lt;</a>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:text>pag</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>      
    <xsl:value-of select="$page"/>      
    <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$pages"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
     <a href="#{$page+1}" onclick="nextPage({$page+1})">&gt;</a>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
   </td> </tr> 
   </table>   
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mp

For completeness I have inlined the Javascript code but of course keeping it in a separate file should make no difference.

Comment: cool .. I need to go now a little bit, but I'll be back shortly, and I'll have you posted about the result.
 Thank you very much for your quick reply.
 Be back in a little while ..

Comment: YES !! It worked !! Really thank you very much!
 And all of you who checked here. 
THANK YOU OH SO MUCH! 
It help me a great deal !
 You guys (Honnen and michael.hor257k) are the best there is !!
 Keep this up