# three records at once xml mobile pagination on xslt - p.III (last)

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

got the following .xml file (which already have it over the following [XSLT get some calculated node value over next line node's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302887/xslt-get-some-calculated-node-value-over-next-line-nodes-value))

```
<upkeepList>
 <upkShare month_year="03-17" post_dte="04-16-17" due="05-02-17"> 
  <OpngBlnce>29</OpngBlnce>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>45</mnthCrrntAmnt>
     <Rcpt dte="05-10-17" No="5815">
      <amnt>50</amnt>
      <descrpt>"03/17-04/17" upkeep</descrpt>
     </Rcpt>
 </upkShare>
 <upkShare month_year="04_17-05_17" post_dte="06-05-17" due="06-30-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>64</mnthCrrntAmnt>
   <Rcpt dte="06-14-17" No="5858">
   <amnt>57</amnt>
   <descrpt>"05/17" upkeep</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
  </upkShare>
<upkShare month_year="06_17" post_dte="07-16-17" due="07-30-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>41</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="07-28-17" No="5948">
   <amnt>50</amnt>
   <descrpt>"06/17" upkeep</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
 </upkShare> 
 <upkShare month_year="07_17" post_dte="08-16-17" due="08-31-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>31</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="08-31-17" No="6002">
   <amnt>53</amnt>
   <descrpt>"07/17" upkeep 1</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
 </upkShare>
<upkShare month_year="08_17" post_dte="09-19-17" due="09-31-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>41</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="09-29-17" No="6026">
   <amnt>41</amnt>
   <descrpt>"07/17" upkeep 1</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
</upkShare>
<upkShare month_year="09_17" post_dte="10-16-17" due="10-31-17">
  <OpngBlnce/>
  <mnthCrrntAmnt>34</mnthCrrntAmnt>
  <Rcpt dte="10-26-17" No="6050">
   <amnt>34</amnt>
   <descrpt>"07/17" upkeep 1</descrpt>
  </Rcpt>
</upkShare>
</upkeepList>
```

```
            Fig.1 xml file maintanance utilities fees
                  which through some .xslt (paged) transposed transformation 
                  it'd looking like as what's reading down over Fig.2
```

[image: p]

```
                  a) data's first page                        b) data's second page
               Fig.2 The way data should display through an xslt (xsl2) transformation
```

... but with regular rows and columns transposed.
Every single line becomes column and each column turns into a row.
Very first column is actually the (records) headers, while the remaining are practically the
records data but (paged) transposed as the columns with only 3 records per page.
Of course at the bottom of the table there goes a pagination area (this part think I know how to do it ..)
As for the first and the second column's cell's meanings, those are depicted as follows:

OB = Opening Balance or Initial Balance;
that's a fixed value by which one opens up the example for line 1/column1;
in the xml file, up through the first principal node , first child node
's value indicates exactly this first initial balance value, by which the whole app
will start;
but starting from the second column, this OB will be reported from previous closing balance
(CB).
ex: OB for col 2 is CB of col 1 (24), then OB for col 3 is CB of col 2 (31), and so on ...
(Remember: here when I refer col, there is actually one record, which normally would goes over one row; but as of this requirment, all the line records will get transposed through columns !)

MUPA = monthly current upkeep amount to pay (MnthlyCrrntAmnt); this is the maintenance fees one
should pay for what utilities have been used during that particular month;

TAP = total amount to pay; TAP = OB + MUPA - this is the TOTAL amount one would pay;

TAPD = total amount paid (receipts sum) - Amount Payed; one does pay some amount either with one, two or even three receipts; sum of all receipts one paid is total amount paid (TAPD);

CB = closing balance (CB) or amount due is the remaing after TAPD is subtracted from TAP (CB = TAP - TAPD)

In the Fig.3 only showed how the calculated fields and node's attribute should looks like to ease up the whole understanding

[image]
Fig. 3 First column's general calculated fields values
along with actual values in col 2 and 3

And, by the way, the very first row of figure 2's data must have "CrntNmbr" header in the
first column and then 1, 2, 3 which obviously represents current number's increment by 1.
But all this figures should go across each row's cols (and not down of the first col's rows) and
eventually limited by 3, which represent the maxim number of column's records per page.
That numbering stuff shoud be done through this sort of xslt "for-each" construct

```
<xsl:for-each select="$var">  <!-- some variable like current() or smthng -->
 <td><xsl:number/></td>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

And the second thing to be pointed is that the first column's headers names explicitly need to
be layed out; perhaps one would use some xslt variable like this one:

```
<xsl:variable name="TblLnHdrs" as="node()*">  
 <xsl:text>CrntNmbr</xsl:text> <xsl:text>MntncPrd</xsl:text> <xsl:text>PostDate</xsl:text> 
 <xsl:text>OpngBalance</xsl:text>   <xsl:text>MnthlyCrrntAmnt</xsl:text<xsl:text>Total</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text> Amount Payed</xsl:text> <xsl:text>Closing Sold</xsl:text><xsl:text>Due</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

Really sorry on keep coming with this silly stuff, but I'm in great need for this ...

Please you guys help me with that xslt 2 transfrmt ...

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Please add information whether you are using some standards compliant XSLT 2.0 processor still supported, like Saxon, or (again?) relying on an abandoned attempt at an implementation of XSLT 2?

Comment: xslt 2 ... Got a little mixed up on your query .. I'll be using saxon, but as xslt 2 for now ..
  thanks